# Is xcode 4.2 is compatible with mac os 10.6.3?

Tags: xcode, macos, operating-system

I have develop an application in xcode 3.2 in mac os 10.6.3, but its not working but in 4.2 its working fine, so I have to download xcode 4.2.
I want to know that Is xcode 4.2 is compatible with mac os 10.6.3 ?

Comment: Do you mean Xcode 4, or IOS SDK 4.2? I cannot find reference to XCode 4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that Xcode 4 has been officially/publicly released, I believe we can answer this question definitively.

Xcode 4 is available through the Mac App Store which requires OS X 10.6.6.
See: http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/xcode/id422352214?mt=12

Of course, the program itself might run under older version of the OS but that usually requires editing .plist files so that the OS version being checked is lower (or the version being reported by the system is higher.)

Answer (score 1):

Questions about pre-release software (Xcode 4) can't be answered in a public forum without violating Apple's license agreement. Instead, you can post your question to Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: The latest released version is Xcode 3.2.5. Xcode 4 is still pre-release at this time.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! can u please explain me What is the difference between xcode and ios sdk.